# 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Router file

```
Route::get('index',[
        'as'=>'home',
        'uses'=>'PageController@getIndex'
]);
```

P age Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class `PageController` extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        return view('master');
    }
}
```

please help me,i tried but there was a problem :NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:
thank so much

Comment: try running `php artisan route:list` and see if your route is registered or not.

Comment: Why is PageController in backticks in your class declaration?

Comment: What URL are you getting the `NotFoundHttpException` at? Your `Route::get('index', ...)` means you need to be browsing to `http://localhost/index` to see this route. Perhaps you meant `Route::get('/', ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

`return view('master');` returns to the folder named master.
Inside that master folder you have to create a blade file, for instance this index.blade.php.

Afterwards you do this in your Controller:

```
return view('master.index');
```

That will link to `resources/views/master/index.blade.php`

Comment: Error is page not found, not view not found.

Answer (score 0):

Just a kind reminder another possible reason causes the issue is that you should put your Route::get(..) into "web.php" not other php files like "api.php" in the routes folder.

Answer (score -1):

Login to Cpanel: locate MultiPHP INI Editor change the desired domain to php7 or above the same page make sure these settings are correct as follows: allow_url_fopen, allow_url_include both enabled display_errors enable_dl disabled Rest is up to your own preference. Then click save.

Now edit your .env file as follows:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel 
APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=base64:#######################= 
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_LOG_LEVEL=false 
APP_URL=https://yourdomain.com
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=password 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Finally, empty your cache and try again. Note that 404 pages will not display unless you create one.

Comment: Where did the OP mention cPanel at all? What does `allow_url_fopen` have to do with any of this? Laravel comes with a 404 page and will display it automatically for any missing routes, too - no need to "create one".